# Cucumber Expressions with CucumberJS 2.0.0+

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, cucumberjs

**Background**

I'm trying my best to figure out CucumberJS 2.0.0, quite a bit has changed since 1.3.0.

Cucumber Expressions can be used in step definitions to replace Regular Expressions:

```
When(/^I search for "{searchTerm}"$/, function (searchTerm) {
```

Instead of:

```
When(/^I search for "([^"]*)"$/, function (searchTerm) {
```

We'd like to use the Cucumber Expressions that seem to be part of CJS2, to make our step definitions more readable (in some places we have quite a bit of regex that would baffle a beginner) and we can't figure out how to do it.

**The Problem**

With reference to the [documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber-expressions/) for Cucumber Expressions, all seems fine, but the `ParameterRegistry` class is undefined within my code.

`ParameterRegistry is not a constructor`

Basically I'm wondering if anyone in the CucumberJS community has managed to get this to work and would help me get started with the Cucumber Expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

`When('I search for {searchTerm:stringInDoubleQuotes}', function (searchTerm)` as an example.

1. It won't take a regex, so it has to be a string
2. You can't have a space between the argument and the parameter type.

To make your own, use the `addTransform` function.

An example:

```
defineSupportCode(function({addTransform}){

    addTransform({
        captureGroupRegexps: ['\\d+(?:|\\.\\d{2})'],
        transformer: JSON.parse,
        typeName: 'money'
    });
});
```

Comment: For anyone who wonders, "addTransform" seems to have been renamed to "defineParameterType", see [this changelog from august](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/052cd2069ad61003974d626406655e8452e27e34/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-08-08) for details.